# How to find SNMP community string?

Tags: snmp

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 and I'm trying to find my SNMP community string.

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_8731252_snmp-community-string-linux.html), but my /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file has different contents than what they're talking about.

- Their snmpd.conf file:  `rocommunity [community string]`
- Mine: `rocommunity public  default    -V systemonly`

That being the case, what is my community string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rocommunity public default -V systemonly`

Your read-only community string is `public`. `default` represents what traffic will be accepted, which is to say all traffic will be accepted. Change `default` to be a hostname or a network address and slash annotated subnet to restrict it further (e.g. `10.4.0.0/16`). The read-only context will be restricted to the `-V systemonly` context which means only OIDS .1.3.6.1.2.1.1 and .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1 will be visible.